# Types and Types Systems concepts

Tags: type-theory, types

**Given this definitions about Types and Type systems :**

Types are described by means of a language of type expressions:

- **Basic** or **primitive types**: Bool, Char, Int, ...
- Type **variables**: a, b, c, ...
- Type **constructors**: → (function), × (tuple), [ ] (list), ...
- **Rules** to build type expressions:

  τ ::= Bool | Char | Int | ··· | t | τ → τ | τ × τ | [ τ ] | ···
- Types whose type expression contains no type variable are called monomorphic types or just monotypes.
- Types whose type expression contains variables are called polytypes or polymorphic types (parametric polymorphism)
- **A polymorphic type represents an infinite number of monotypes**

I'm trying to understand the last definition but i can't.
A polymorphic type represents a infinite number of monoytpes, because in his type expression has a type variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Because you can instantiate the polymorphic type with an infinite amount of (mono)types.

For example, the type $a \to a$ (which is a polymrphic type) represents

- Bool $\to$ Bool
- Char $\to$ Char
- (Char $\to$ Int) $\to$ (Char $\to$ Int)
- etc...